# Calculus Implicit Differentiation &Partial Diff.

Tags: calculus

> Express v$_x$ in terms of u and y if the equations x =vln(u) and y= uln(v) define u and v as functions of the independent variables x and y, and if v$_x$ exists.

Implicitly differentiating a function gives:

(1) (ln(u)v$_x$) + (v/u)u$_x$ = 1

(2) (u/v)v$_x$ + (ln(v)u$_x$) = 0;

Now I have to solve for v$_x$, which should be no problem, but I think I am tripping over algebra.

Textbook pulls some formula out of thin air and gives answer ln(v)  / (ln(u) ln(v)-1).

Anyone got any idea?

Comment: The problem I am having is with eliminating u$_x$. How do I get rid of that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
x = v\ln u\\
y = u\ln v.
$$
Taking logs of the first equation we get
$$
\ln x = \ln v  + \ln \ln u.
$$
We can now sub $y$ in and get
$$
\ln x = \frac{y}{u} + \ln \ln u
$$
Take the derivatives with respect to $x$ we find
$$
\frac{1}{x} = -\frac{y}{u^2}u_x +\frac{1}{u\ln u}u_x
$$
We have an equation for $x$ for later.
Taking the derivative of our initial second equation we find
$$
0 = u_x \ln v + \frac{u}{v}v_x \implies \frac{u_x }{u}= -\frac{1}{v\ln v}v_x
$$
So we have
$$
\frac{1}{x} = -\frac{u_x}{u}\left[\frac{y}{u}-\frac{1}{\ln u}\right] = \frac{1}{v\ln v}\left[\frac{y}{u}-\frac{1}{\ln u}\right]v_x = \frac{1}{v\ln u}
$$
Re-arrange we find $v_x$ as 
$$
v_x = \frac{\ln v}{\ln u \left[\frac{y}{u}-\frac{1}{\ln u}\right]}
$$
Now you have 
$$
\frac{y}{u} =\ln v
$$
Now you are done.
I went the long way just to be simpler (but you can take short cuts).

Comment: Thank you for your help. I thought I needed to derive something for u$_x$, since we had two equations and two variables (v$_x$ and u$_u$). Fortunately your solution worked and I can now solve this!